# What is Controlled in a TableView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am experimenting creating views that contain **View** based TableViews, ie: NSOutlineView and would like to better understand the correct connections that are made within IB.

At the moment, I have created a MainWindow that has the AppDelegate assigned to it.

On top of this, I have introduced a NSOutlineView which ultimately have an array as its data source.

I would like to have a separate Controller to look after this and its sub-views.

The NSOutlineView is made up of:

- NSTableColumn
- NSTableViewCell
- NSTextField

With my NSTableCellView  I have added two NSTextFields, the top one will be used as a Title and the second is a mini and will be used for displaying descriptions.

The issue I am facing is what controls need to have an IBOutlet connected to it.

My logic is; the only controls that will exhibit a change are the NSTableView as there needs to be a separate TableView within the TableColumn which will be a result of the item.count in the array.

Secondly, I am assuming that an IBOutlet will need to point to each of the TextField’s in the TableViewCell which will allow them to display the correct information for each item.count in the array.

So, all I need to do is design a Controller that has **three** IBOutlets.

Have I got my basics right…..  or am I way off track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get everything you are asking for but first of all you don't set outlet to your `NSTableView` you need to use a `NSArrayController`, KVC and bindings.

1) in your AppDelegate.h create an `IBOutlet` to your `NSArrayController`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
IBOutlet NSArrayController *yourArrayController;
}
```

2) in AppDelegate.m put your input or whatever in the `NSArrayController`:

```
yourItem *newItem = [[yourItem alloc] init];
[newItem setValue:[_inputVar stringValue] forKey:@"name"]; //use Key Value Coding
...
[yourArrayController addObject:newItem];
```

3) now go to your .xib and draw a `NSArrayController` object (green bubble with 3 blue cubes) in the dock (the area left to the .xib).

4) in your tableview click three times at each row and open the `Bindings inspector`

5) go to "Value" and activate "Bind to", select `yourArrayController`

6) set `Controller Key` to "arrangedObjects"

7) write the appropriate key in `Model Key Path`

Do that for each tableview column and you should be fine basically. No `IBOutlet` from the controller to you `NSTableView`!

The `NSArrayController` is taking care about user input back an forth to and from your tableview which is pretty convenient. I know not to answer all your questions but it might help you to get started. Good luck!